# Moved Projects keep showing up in TFS explorer - TFS 2010

Tags: tfs

I'm using TFS 2010 withing VS.Net 2012.  Another developer moved a few branches/projects to an "archive" but they still show up in the original folder for me.  The developer sent me a screen shot showing his TFS Explorer without the branches  in the main folder, but I can still see them.

What gives?  We're just trying to get a clean active folder.

Comment: Where are you seeing them? Do you have it set to show deleted files?

Comment: Maybe.  Where is the setting for that?

Comment: If you have, it'll show "Deleted" in the status column, in Source Control Explorer. I've not got VS2010 to hand, and the settings seem to move with every version :)

Comment: I found the setting, it is not selected

Comment: FYI, The issue had to do with TFS caching my Workspace mappings.  When a branch was moved to archive my workspace still had the old mapping.